# DataContractSerializer behaves in confusing ways with KnownTypes and Generics

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, datacontractserializer, known-types

I'm trying to generate KnownType lists for arbitrary objects, and I'm running into problems when trying to serialize types with generic members, such as `DbEntityValidationException` which has a list property of type `IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult>`.

When calling the constructor for DataContractSerializer, I feed it a list of KnownTypes consisting of the following types, constructed by using reflection to grab the types of all of its properties, as well as any generic type arguments:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(source.GetType(), knownsTypesPlusGenerics);
var stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    serializer.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, source);
}
```

This list consists of the following types, captured via tracing:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult
```

Yet, for some reason, DataContractSerializer throws on missing types, as if the type of the list property was `List<object>` instead of `List<DbEntityValidationResult>`:

``` System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer. ```

Why would DataContractSerializer complain about this type when that type isn't used, and when I've provided the type that actually is?

Comment: Did you get around to resolving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that somewhere in your object graph, List<{object}> needs to be serialized.

DataContractSerializer sees List<{object}> as being different than List<{any other type}> so typeof(List<{object}>) must be one of the Type's passed on to the DataContractSerializer constructor.

Try that and see if it helps.